# Primeng dynamic dialog draggable

Tags: primeng, primeng-dialog

Primeng v15.2.0 available draggable properties. but we should enable dynamic dialog header for drag dynamic dialog. I tried other draggable plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-draggable), it's not working in primeng. the requirement is the popup structure should not change and should be dragable. if move the mouse to body content then draggable icon disappeared. The popup structure changed if i enable the dynamic dialog header. any solution for drag dynamic dialog without header.